# Spring boot: parameter 0 of method of someclass required a bean of type someotherclass that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a problem when I launch my spring boot app.

In a configuration file, I gave

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public someClass method(someOtherClass obj)
{
}
```

And then I accessed the bean by

```
someClass obj = (someClass)context.getBean("someClass",object)
```

That object is passed as an argument to the bean, but spring boot tries to ask a bean for that argument.

This is not an issue in the spring application. But when I use the same code in the spring boot 2.0 version, this error occurs.

Comment: What is someOtherClass?

Comment: is this the actual code from your application or rather pseudo code? Can you add also how you provide `someOtherClass` as a Spring Bean

Comment: just pseudo code, it is not a Spring bean, I pass it as an argument in getBean method

Comment: @YuvarajaP Did you managed to fix it somehow? I getting the same error and it drives me crazy ._.

Answer (score 0):

It's bean name is not "someClass", but "method".

```java
someClass obj = (someClass)context.getBean("mathod",object);
```